# Restoring original system state Aborting

Tags: apt, do-release-upgrade

```
dj@dj:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                              
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,258 kB]                                                                                                                                     
Fetched 1,259 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                    
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'
Reading cache
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                          
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                                                                          
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                                                                                                                 
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                                                                        
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]                                                                                         
Fetched 323 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
dj@dj:~$
```

Comment: facing same issue...

Answer (score -1):

You will have to remove the PPA which were added to the system

Step 1: List the PPAs

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | \
    while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {print "sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5}' "$file"; done
```

Step 2: Now, remove them

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | \
    while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {system("sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5)}' "$file"; done
```

Step 3: Install `bleachbit` and `gtkorphan`

```
sudo apt install bleachbit
sudo apt install gtkorphan
```

Step 4: Run `bleachbit` and `gtkorphan`as `root`

Step 5: Now, run the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Please do not repost this answer many times to many questions.  If the questions are similar enough to be duplicates covered by the same question and answer, flag the questions as duplicates.  (Your other verbatim copies of this answer have been deleted, as reposting the same answer many times is considered noise to some extent)

Comment: Should i report those questions?